# Como Gerar XML de duas tabelas tipo Nota e Itens da Nota Hierarquicamente

Tags: xml

Pessoal gostaria de criar  o XML de duas tabelas Imagine um exemplo abaixo

CREATE TABLE T_PARENT (ID NUMBER,
                       TOTAL_VALUE NUMBER,
                       LOCAL_OPERATION VARCHAR2(100),
                       AGENT_OPERATOR VARCHAR2(50),
                       BANK_OPERATOR VARCHAR2(10),
    CONSTRAINT T_PARENT_pk PRIMARY KEY (ID)  );
 CREATE TABLE T_CHILD (ID_CHILD NUMBER,
                       ID_PARENT NUMBER,
                       VALUE_OPERATION NUMBER,
                       QTD_OPERATION   NUMBER,
 CONSTRAINT T_CHILD_pk PRIMARY KEY (ID_CHILD),
  CONSTRAINT fk_ID
    FOREIGN KEY (ID_PARENT)
    REFERENCES T_PARENT(ID));

```
INSERT INTO T_PARENT (id,total_value,Local_Operation,Agent_Operator,bank_operator) VALUES (1,1000,'PORTUGAL','SOARES','BBV');
INSERT INTO T_PARENT VALUES (2,200,'ENGLAND','BLAIR','BBA');
```

insert into t_child values(1,1,200,1);
   insert into t_child values(2,1,200,3);
   insert into t_child values (3,1,100,1);
   insert into t_child values(4,1,100,1);
   insert into t_child values(5,2,50,2);
   insert into t_child values(6,2,100,1);

Gostaria que fosse exibido assim ,  primeiro dados da tabela Pai (T_PARENT) e seus respectivos filhos (T_CHILD), mas as colunas **Em ordem alfabética**

  SOARES 
  BBV
  1
  PORTUGAL
  1000
 
  1
  1
  1
   200
   
   
    1
    1
    1
    200
     
    
    2
    1
    3
    200
    
    
    3
    1
    1
    100
    
     
    4
    1
    1
    100
    
    
    BLAIR
    BBA
    2
    ENGLAND
    200
  
    5
    2
     2
    50
   
   
    6
    2
     1
    100

Comment: Qual linguagem você vai gerar o XML?

Comment: Minha pergunta ficou muito ruim ,  estou usando ORACLE  e através do join  de duas tabelas  criar as Tags hierarquicamente